# pass parameters from a javascript function (in a HTML form)

Tags: javascript

I would like to know whether it is possible to pass parameters from a javascript function (in a HTML form).
Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: please give more details on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some values in your JavaScript to be added to the POST generated by the form, pop their values into hidden fields.

```
<form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return myFunction();">
<input type="hidden" name="calculatedTotal" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction() {
      document.myform.calculatedTotal.value = (100 / 4);
      return true;
   }
</script>
```